# creating a new variable using dplyr and ifelse where more than one conditions are used

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data set. I want to create a variable called "specialized". For creating the variable, I need to group the data by using group_by (sic, year). Then the dummy variable "specialized" will be created -

if in a given "year and "sic", the "percentage" variable is the highest AND the difference between the highest percentage and the second highest percentage is greater than 10, then it will be coded "1", "0" otherwise.

However, Note that if in a given "year" and "sic", there is no second highest percentage - meaning that only one percentage, which is the highest - then it will be coded 1. This kind of case is "sic ==0100" in "year==2000"in my data set.

I tried the following code

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(sic, year) %>% 
  mutate(SPECIALIZED = ifelse(max(percentage) && (max(percentage)-nth(sort(percentage), - 2)) > 10), 1, 0 ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

But it does not work.

Here is the data -

```
   gvkey auditor_fkey  year  sic  percentage
1  001266            4 2001 0100  26.9605909
2  003107            2 2000 1000  37.0939127
3  003107            2 2000 1000  37.0939127
4  003107            2 2001 1000   9.8899690
5  003107            2 2001 1000   9.8899690
6  005560            1 2000 1040 100.0000000
7  005560            7 2001 1040   8.2959428
8  007881            5 2001 1040  71.1026743
9  009728          597 2001 1040   1.0906007
10 009728          597 2001 1040   1.0906007
11 010390            2 2000 0100 100.0000000
12 010390            2 2000 0100 100.0000000
13 010390            2 2001 0100  73.0394091
14 010390            2 2001 0100  73.0394091
15 012321            1 2001 1040  18.1873703
16 012321            1 2001 1040  18.1873703
17 014590            5 2000 1000  60.6862904
18 014590            5 2000 1000  60.6862904
19 014590            5 2001 1000  18.8287898
20 014590            5 2001 1000  18.8287898
21 014793            2 2000 1220  34.7515455
22 014793            2 2000 1220  34.7515455
23 014793            2 2001 1220  58.0859392
24 014793            2 2001 1220  58.0859392
25 015274            1 2000 1220  65.2484545
26 015274            1 2000 1220  65.2484545
27 015274            1 2001 1220  41.9140608
28 015274            1 2001 1220  41.9140608
29 019565            1 2001 1000  71.1457384
30 019565            1 2001 1000  71.1457384
31 020488            1 2000 1040 100.0000000
32 020488            1 2001 1040  18.1873703
33 025776            1 2000 1000   2.2197969
34 025776            1 2001 1000  71.1457384
35 031626            2 2000 1000  37.0939127
36 031626            2 2001 1000   9.8899690
37 061811            5 2000 1000  60.6862904
38 061811            5 2001 1000  18.8287898
39 061811            5 2001 1000  18.8287898
40 064134          580 2001 1000   0.1355028
41 064134          580 2001 1000   0.1355028
42 065921            1 2000 1040 100.0000000
43 065921            1 2000 1040 100.0000000
44 065921            1 2001 1040  18.1873703
45 065921            1 2001 1040  18.1873703
46 102341            2 2001 1040   1.3234119
47 142460            2 2001 1220  58.0859392
48 142460            2 2001 1220  58.0859392
49 142460            2 2001 1220  58.0859392
```

The final data set should be look like this --

```
    gvkey auditor_fkey year sic  percentage      specialized
1   10390            2 2000 0100 100.0000000           1
2   10390            2 2000 0100 100.0000000           1
3    3107            2 2000 1000  37.0939127           0
4    3107            2 2000 1000  37.0939127           0
5   14590            5 2000 1000  60.6862904           1
6   14590            5 2000 1000  60.6862904           1
7   25776            1 2000 1000   2.2197969           0
8   31626            2 2000 1000  37.0939127           0
9   61811            5 2000 1000  60.6862904           1
10   5560            1 2000 1040 100.0000000           1
11  20488            1 2000 1040 100.0000000           1
12  65921            1 2000 1040 100.0000000           1
13  65921            1 2000 1040 100.0000000           1
14  14793            2 2000 1220  34.7515456           0
15  14793            2 2000 1220  34.7515456           0
16  15274            1 2000 1220  65.2484544           1
17  15274            1 2000 1220  65.2484544           1
18   1266            4 2001 0100  26.9605909           0
19  10390            2 2001 0100  73.0394091           1
20  10390            2 2001 0100  73.0394091           1
21   3107            2 2001 1000   9.8899690           0
22   3107            2 2001 1000   9.8899690           0
23  14590            5 2001 1000  18.8287898           0
24  14590            5 2001 1000  18.8287898           0
25  19565            1 2001 1000  71.1457384           1
26  19565            1 2001 1000  71.1457384           1
27  25776            1 2001 1000  71.1457384           1
28  31626            2 2001 1000   9.8899690           0
29  61811            5 2001 1000  18.8287898           0
30  61811            5 2001 1000  18.8287898           0
31  64134          580 2001 1000   0.1355028           0
32  64134          580 2001 1000   0.1355028           0
33   5560            7 2001 1040   8.2959428           0
34   7881            5 2001 1040  71.1026743           1
35   9728          597 2001 1040   1.0906007           0
36   9728          597 2001 1040   1.0906007           0
37  12321            1 2001 1040  18.1873703           0
38  12321            1 2001 1040  18.1873703           0
39  20488            1 2001 1040  18.1873703           0
40  65921            1 2001 1040  18.1873703           0
41  65921            1 2001 1040  18.1873703           0
42 102341            2 2001 1040   1.3234119           0
43  14793            2 2001 1220  58.0859392           1
44  14793            2 2001 1220  58.0859392           1
45  15274            1 2001 1220  41.9140608           0
46  15274            1 2001 1220  41.9140608           0
47 142460            2 2001 1220  58.0859392           1
48 142460            2 2001 1220  58.0859392           1
49 142460            2 2001 1220  58.0859392           1
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is `&&` - try `&` instead.

Comment: The `max(percentage)` is not logical

Comment: The input and output values are not the same.  Please check

Comment: @ thelatemail Even if I fix    && it does not work.

Comment: @Sharif  How did the `001266` for first row in gvkey changed to `10309` in output

Comment: Based on your description, `df %>% group_by(sic, year) %>% mutate(new = as.integer((max(percentage) - nth(sort(percentage), -2)) > 10))`

Comment: Or `df %>% group_by(sic, year) %>% mutate(new = as.integer(diff(tail(sort(percentage), 2)) > 10))`

Comment: @ akrun it is sorted. in the input data set it is for year 2001, but in output data set it is sorted by year and sic. therefore it changes. what your variable "new" mean? why you created it?

Comment: Just as a place holder, because typing `specialized` takes more time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order changed in you data and the expected result. So I took the data from the result instead. Here is breakdown of the logic into seperate columns before creating the dummy with `dummy` from `hablar`.

```
library(hablar)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(sic, year) %>% 
  mutate(second_highest = nth(sort(unique(percentage), decreasing = T), 2), 
         max_value = max(percentage),
         is_max   = percentage == max_value,
         is_ab_10 = (max_value - second_highest) > 10,
         specialized = dummy(is_max & is_ab_10, missing = 1)
    ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(second_highest, max_value, is_max, is_ab_10))
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 49 x 6
   gvkey auditor_fkey  year   sic percentage specialized
   <int>        <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>       <int>
 1 10390            2  2000   100     100              1
 2 10390            2  2000   100     100              1
 3  3107            2  2000  1000      37.1            0
 4  3107            2  2000  1000      37.1            0
 5 14590            5  2000  1000      60.7            1
 6 14590            5  2000  1000      60.7            1
 7 25776            1  2000  1000       2.22           0
 8 31626            2  2000  1000      37.1            0
 9 61811            5  2000  1000      60.7            1
10  5560            1  2000  1040     100              1
# … with 39 more rows
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(gvkey = c(10390L, 10390L, 3107L, 3107L, 14590L, 
                         14590L, 25776L, 31626L, 61811L, 5560L, 20488L, 65921L, 65921L, 
                         14793L, 14793L, 15274L, 15274L, 1266L, 10390L, 10390L, 3107L, 
                         3107L, 14590L, 14590L, 19565L, 19565L, 25776L, 31626L, 61811L, 
                         61811L, 64134L, 64134L, 5560L, 7881L, 9728L, 9728L, 12321L, 12321L, 
                         20488L, 65921L, 65921L, 102341L, 14793L, 14793L, 15274L, 15274L, 
                         142460L, 142460L, 142460L), auditor_fkey = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                      5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                      2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 580L, 580L, 7L, 5L, 597L, 
                                                                      597L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), year = c(2000L, 
                                                                                                                                          2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
                                                                                                                                          2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 
                                                                                                                                          2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
                                                                                                                                          2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
                                                                                                                                          2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
                                                                                                                                          2001L, 2001L, 2001L), sic = c(100L, 100L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1220L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        1220L, 1220L, 1220L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1040L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        1220L, 1220L, 1220L, 1220L, 1220L, 1220L, 1220L), percentage = c(100, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         100, 37.0939127, 37.0939127, 60.6862904, 60.6862904, 2.2197969, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         37.0939127, 60.6862904, 100, 100, 100, 100, 34.7515456, 34.7515456, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         65.2484544, 65.2484544, 26.9605909, 73.0394091, 73.0394091, 9.889969, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         9.889969, 18.8287898, 18.8287898, 71.1457384, 71.1457384, 71.1457384, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         9.889969, 18.8287898, 18.8287898, 0.1355028, 0.1355028, 8.2959428, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         71.1026743, 1.0906007, 1.0906007, 18.1873703, 18.1873703, 18.1873703, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         18.1873703, 18.1873703, 1.3234119, 58.0859392, 58.0859392, 41.9140608, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         41.9140608, 58.0859392, 58.0859392, 58.0859392)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -49L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi @davsjob Thank you very much for your help. It works now.